# Matlab - Assigning matching variables between two data sets and creating a new table

Tags: python, matlab, datatables, data-analysis

I'm currently working with two data sets, as shown below:

Data set 1:

| Point_ID | Record | Difference (m) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2804AJGCA57' | 'Record003 - 220428_103738_Scanner_1 - 2804AJGCA57' | '0.035240' |
| '2804AJGCA28' | 'Record003 - 220428_103738_Scanner_1 - 2804AJGCA28' | '0.030961' |
| '2804AJGCA29' | 'Record003 - 220428_103738_Scanner_1 - 2804AJGCA29' | '0.030219' |

Data set 2:

| Point_ID | Easting | Northing | Elevation_OD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '2804AJGCA1' | '200305.3884' | '80809.76627' | '7.25913' |
| '2804AJGCA2' | '200304.9855' | '80809.20396' | '7.23274' |
| '2804AJGCA3' | '200304.3783' | '80808.51888' | '7.20207' |

Essentially, I need to compare the 1st column of both tables and if the 'Point_ID' from the 2nd data set is found within the 1st, I need to add the 'Difference (m)' column onto the corresponding 'Point_ID' row, in the 2nd data set, or a new table.

I hope that this makes sense. Currently I have the following code:

```
%% Import CSVs

GCA_data = readtable('Input/Test/GCA&GCP_Results_Flight1.csv', 'Delimiter',';', 'Format','%s %s %s'); %Insert pathway to GCA_Results csv.

XYZ_data= readtable('Input/Test/GCA&GCP_Flight1.csv','Delimiter',',','Format','%s %s %s %s'); %Insert pathway to the GCA XYZ file inputted into RiProcess.


%% Pre - Settings

ids = GCA_data.Object1; %Identifies all points that were used within the GCA calculations

nids = numel(ids); % Identifies the number of unique point ids.

gca_table = [];

for ii = 1:nids; 
   
    ID = ids{ii}; %Speicifies the point ID. 
    
    idx = ismember()
end
```

Comment: Hi @Adam Johns can please give your desire output? because that point_id is not matching.

Comment: Sorry the above table examples are only a snippet, however there are matches between the two table columns. But, my desired output would be a table with the following columns: 'Point_ID (Where they match)', 'Easting', 'Northing', 'Elevation_OD', 'Difference (m)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of `join` operation. MATLAB can do various different joins on `table`. See [this doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/jointables.html) for more. I'm not sure, but I think you want a "left" join - this is what you need if some entries aren't present, like in this example:

```
t1 = table(["aaa"; "bbb"; "ccc"], [1; 2; 3], ...
    'VariableNames', {'Point_ID', 'Difference (m)'});
t2 = table(["bbb"; "ccc"; "ddd"], [200; 300; 400], ...
    'VariableNames', {'Point_ID', 'OtherValue'});

% Match up rows by "Point_ID", get "Difference (m)" if
% available and add to "OtherValue". 
% MergeKeys=true means keep only one copy of the key "Point_ID"
outerjoin(t2, t1, type="left", MergeKeys=true)
```

Which gets:

```
  3×3 table

    Point_ID    OtherValue    Difference (m)
    ________    __________    ______________

     "bbb"         200               2      
     "ccc"         300               3      
     "ddd"         400             NaN
```

Comment: Amazing, this is by far the quickest method. Who knew that matlab could behave like SQL?!

Answer (score 1):

this is tagged as Python so I'll give you a python code solution:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

GCA_data=pd.read_csv('GCA_Results csv', sep=';', header=True)
XYZ_data=pd.read_csv('GCA&GCP_Flight1.csv', sep=',', header=True)

GCA_data=GCA_data.set_index(GCA_data['Point_ID'])
XYZ_data=XYZ_data.set_index(XYZ_data['Point_ID'])
*Anyname*= pd.concat([XYZ_data,GCA_data['Difference (m)']], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
*Anyname*.to_csv('Anyname',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question correct, as their no match between both table points I am compare by starts match. By first converting the df1's pointID and difference columns to dict.

For ex, 2804AJGCA28 == 2804AJGCA2

Code:

```
dic = pd.Series(df1['Difference (m)'].values,index=df1['Point_ID']).to_dict()
df2['Difference (m)'] = df2['Point_ID'].apply(lambda x:  [ v for k,v in dic.items() if x in k])
df2
```

Output:

```
      Point_ID      Easting    Northing Elevation_OD    Difference (m)
0   2804AJGCA1  200305.3884 80809.76627 7.25913                     []
1   2804AJGCA2  200304.9855 80809.2039  7.23274   [0.030961, 0.030219]
2   2804AJGCA3  200304.3783 80808.51888 7.20207                     []
```

Otherwise, if you have match between pointID you can remove loop and startswith logic and just

`df2['Point_ID'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df1['Difference (m)'].values,index=df1['Point_ID']).to_dict()[x] )`